# Problems with bone roll on rigify paw

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

The legs on a model I'm working with is messed up by the rig, and I'm pretty sure the culprit is the rolls on some of the leg bones. My problem is I'm not sure how to orient it and which bones to fix. I've tried multiple methods but to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if your problem is not that all these bones...

[image]

...should not be in *Local Space* in their *Copy Transform* constraint (instead of *World Space*):

[image]

Comment: Looks like that worked. Not sure why rigify didn't fix it automatically.

Comment: I can't tell, I don't know Rigify ;)